# prime gaps 4*n+1 or 4*n+3

Tags: prime-numbers

Take the two prime gaps of $4*n+1$ and $4*n+3$ and the first ten million primes.  Will we find that the number of gaps for each is about the same?  One could see the possibilility of a prime gap race similar to that for primes of the form $4*n+1$ and $4*n+3$.  Has anyone done this?

Comment: What do you mean by the two prime gaps?  What are the two gaps when $n=10?$ say.

Comment: If n =10, then the number of terms between the two primes is 10-1=9=4*n+1.  The difference between the primes is one thing, and the number of terms between them is an other.  Take 17,19 and the prime gap is 4*0+1 and for 19,23 the prime gap is 4*0+3.

Comment: I got $$[4448503, 5551496]$$ The first entry is the number of gaps with residue $0$ modulo $4$ and the second the number of gaps with residue $2$ modulo $4$. Seems that residue $2$ modulo $4$  occurs significantly more often.

Comment: I dare say, the rare courageous and bold getting the computer to produce some data!  Odd that the second gives 6 while the first gives 12,24,36,48 and other multiples of 12.  It appears that the second with 6, 18,30,42...is enough to be a winner.